# Timeout when trying to open a SSH Remote, but the same server under a different remote target works correctly

Tags: vscode-remote

I have a ubuntu VM with multiple IP addresses, all in the same subnet. SSHD is listening on a single IP, 192.168.101.87/24.

My SSH config file has this server under the name dockerhost, and the HostName is configured as the IP address. The config block is below.

```
Host dockerhost 192.168.101.87
  HostName 192.168.101.87
  User webtroter
  ForwardAgent yes
```

I have been using this config for a long time without problems.

Usually, I open the remote sidepanel, and I open the workspace docker-veznet.

[[image: Two Remote Target, with two recents each]

But now, when I try to open a folder/file/workspace on the remote dockerhost, it times-out everytime. I can open the remote directly with VSCode (without opening a folder/file/workspace), but as soon as I open the docker-veznet folder (or the associated workspace) the remote times-out.

I just tried doing a copy of the folder, and I was able to open it. I also tried to open the same folder, but under another remote Target (192.168.101.87) and it opens correctly.

I would like some help finding what I need to check to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found that there is a GitHub Issue opened about this problem.

The issue is caused by the secondary side bar.

Link to comment in the issue about how to fix : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7324#issuecomment-1307954310

Comment: if you answered your own question please mark it as solved

Comment: I thought that accepting an answer would do it.